# How to generate SSL certificate for application hosted in tomcat in Windows OS-not self-signed

Tags: windows, tomcat, ssl, operating-system, certificate

Can anyone please let me know how I can generate a certificate for my web application secured and hosted using tomcat 7 in Windows OS and which is not self-signed. Basically users should not get any security constraint in accessing the web application like untrusted certificate.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a self-signed certificate, then you'll just have to get someone else to sign it.

Those "someone else's" are called Certificate Authorities, and there are many of them. Some are more expensive than others, and some are entirely free if you jump through some hoops to get validated in some way.

Do some web searching for "Certificate Authority" and I'm sure you'll find someone to take your money and sign your certificate for you.

Comment: I am looking for some free CA basically. If you can recommend, that will be great!

Comment: SO isn't supposed to recommend products/services. Just search online and read reviews/complaints/etc.